# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined Heroku

Tags: reactjs

I've tried to figured out what's going on here, but sometimes when it's too easy I can't find it. So I'm asking for help. Thanks for all your suggestions

https://github.com/Vamusmart/newsappteam

```
 2 | class Feed extends React.Component {
      3 |   render() {
      4 |     return (
    > 5 |       <div>
      6 |         {this.props.data.map(article => (
      7 |           <div className="grid-container">
      8 | 

        <a className="content-title" href={article.url}> 


  19 |   const data = await api_call.json();
  20 |   console.log(data.articles);
  21 | 
> 22 |   this.setState({
     | ^  23 |     homepageData: data.articles
  24 |   });
  25 | };
```

Comment: Add a little bit more context to your question, what have you tried? Where are you getting the error, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Please refrain from posting duplicate questions.**

Nevertheless, as the error message says, the property `map` cannot be found on `undefined`. This means that the value on which you are trying to iterate is `undefined`. In this case, it is due to: `this.props.data === undefined`.

You can counter this by defining the default value for this prop (or state in parent component) as an empty array. You can also specifically handle the empty condition and only map if your variable has a valid/expected type.